# Merge two versions of the same git repo

Tags: git

I currently have two Git repos that were created from the same SVN repo at different moments in time.  One of the Git repos is local to my box (in folder `temp`), the other one is a remote repo that I have cloned to a different folder on my box (`SS`).  The local repo is the most current repo.  How can I use Git to update the remote repo with just the deltas from when the remote repo was created until today's latest change?

Below is what I have tried

```
cd SS
git add remote temp ../temp
git fetch temp
```

Results:

```
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 77563, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (25852/25852), done.
remote: Total 77563 (delta 42638), reused 75783 (delta 40858)
Receiving objects: 100% (77563/77563), 45.68 MiB | 1.23 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (42638/42638), done.
```

I thought that I would need to do a rebase, so I typed

```
git rebase master
```

Results:

```
Current branch master is up to date.
```

Then I was confused, so I did a

```
git status
```

Results:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

If this had worked the way I thought it would, it should have had the deltas added to `temp` from the time `SS` was created until today.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If `SS` repo has no changes and local one is the one most up to date, just do the `git push --force`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rebase command gives `Current branch master is up to date.` because you are still `On branch master`; you have fetched `temp`, but you haven't changed branches, so the rebase has no effect.

What you probably meant to do was:

```
git checkout -b temp temp/master
git rebase master
```

And after that:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only temp
git svn dcommit
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for your help.